# Comparing DataTable cells from two DataTables

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, compare, cell

I've been working on a project that will use NLP to define DataTable values. I've already gotten that function up. However, I've ran into some issues when working with DataTables.

I will have two different DataTables, both of different formats

e.g.:

**TABLE1**

|Column 1|

**TABLE2**

|Column 1|Column 2|

In DataTable2, Column 2 is a corresponding value to Column 1.
I intend to compare the cell contents of both DataTables' Column 1s, and run it through my NLP. If they have a certain matching percentage, I will write them to another DataTable. If they fail to match, I'll just leave it blank.
So for example:

**If >75% match**

**TABLE3**

|DT1 Col 1| DT2 Col 1 | DT2 Col 2|

**If <75% match**

**TABLE3**

|DT1 Col 1| " " | " "

Is what I'm aiming to do programatically possible? I've pseudo code in mind if it helps explain it better.

```
foreach(DataRow in Table1)
   foreach(DataRow in Table2)
      if(comparison score >=75.00)
            Write to table3
      else
            Write to table3 with blanks
```

I'd appreciate any help on this problem. I'll still be doing my own research though, and I'll post back if I make any breakthroughs.

EDIT:
I've just realized the rows in the two DataTables might not necessarily correspond, so I'll have to run the comparison against all cells. Is that possible?

It doesn't necessarily have to be working with DataTables though, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Is it required to work with DataTables? Why not make a class that represents the entity for table 1 and 2?

Comment: @jfs guess DataTables aren't mandatory. But i'll be working with CSV files so... Does that change things?

Comment: I don't think so. It would be easier for you to do computations using the entities than using the datatables. Another advantage is that you can explicitly put the constraints on the class.

Answer (score 1):

so I've figured out an inelegant solution due to time constraints (and desperation).

I've used a nested *foreach* - *for* loop to traverse both DataTables. Code below:

```
            foreach (DataRow dRow in dt1.Rows)
            {
                a = dRow[0].ToString();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    b = dt2.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    if (hcontroller.GetScore(a, b) >= 90.00)
                    {
                        c = dt2.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        match = false;
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                if (match)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(a, b, c);
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(a, "No close matches found!", "");
                }
            }
```

However, I'm highly certain that when the DataTables get to a certain size, the operation will be highly memory consuming. Additionally, the *if* statement eliminates the likelihood of finding a better match.

I'm open to other suggestions if any. But I hope this helps anyone stuck with the same problem I'm facing. Cheers!